# Execution failed for task ':java-source:deployNodes'. (Installing Corda). Any Suggestions?

Tags: corda

I am trying to install **Corda** onto my local laptop. I get a build error as described below. Can anyone help?

I am running this -

```
~/kotlinapps/cordapp-example$ ./gradlew deployNodes --scan
```

> > Task :java-source:deployNodes  Bootstrapping local network in /Users/satoshimaca/kotlinapps/cordapp-example/java-source/build/nodes
> >     Node config files found in the root directory - generating node
> >     directories Generating directory for Notary Generating directory for
> >     PartyA Generating directory for PartyC Generating directory for PartyB
> >     Nodes found in the following sub-directories: [Notary, PartyA, PartyC,
> >     PartyB] Waiting for all nodes to generate their node-info files...
>
> **FAILURE:** Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task `':java-source:deployNodes'.`
>
>   > Node in Notary exited with 1 when generating its node-info - see logs in
>   >     /Users/satoshimaca/kotlinapps/cordapp-example/java-source/build/nodes/Notary/logs
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2m 0s 5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
>   `~/kotlinapps/cordapp-example$ ./gradlew deployNodes` --scan Download
>   https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/gradle/build-scan-plugin/1.10.3/build-scan-plugin-1.10.3.pom
>   Download
>   https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.1.60/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.1.60.pom
>   Download
>   https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/gradle/build-scan-plugin/1.10.3/build-scan-plugin-1.10.3.jar
>   Download
>   https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.1.60/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.1.60.jar
>
> > Task :java-source:deployNodes  Bootstrapping local network in /Users/satoshimaca/kotlinapps/cordapp-example/java-source/build/nodes
> >     Node config files found in the root directory - generating node
> >     directories Generating directory for Notary Generating directory for
> >     PartyA Generating directory for PartyC Generating directory for PartyB
> >     Nodes found in the following sub-directories: [Notary, PartyA, PartyC,
> >     PartyB] Waiting for all nodes to generate their node-info files...
>
> **FAILURE:** Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task `':java-source:deployNodes'.`
>
>   > Node in Notary exited with 1 when generating its node-info - see logs in
>   >     /Users/satoshimaca/kotlinapps/cordapp-example/java-source/build/nodes/Notary/logs
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 3s
>
> 5 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 3 up-to-date
>
> Publishing a build scan to scans.gradle.com requires accepting the
>   Terms of Service defined at https://scans.gradle.com/terms-of-service.
>   Do you accept these terms? [yes, no] Gradle Cloud Services license
>   agreement accepted.
>
> Publishing build scan... https://gradle.com/s/u5os3dq6zfl3a

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know what's going on here. Please post the notary node's logs under `/Users/satoshimaca/kotlinapps/cordapp-example/java-source/build/nodes/Notary/logs` so we can help better.

However, two possibilities are:

- Old builds are corrupting the process. Run `./gradlew clean deployNodes` instead of `./gradlew deployNodes`
- You are using an incompatible JVM version. You need to use version 8u131 or above of the Oracle JDK 8 JVM

Comment: I will try and reproduce the error. This is an old one now.

Comment: I understand :)

Comment: @TrevorOakley I am experiencing this same error, anything you did to fix it would be very helpful.

Comment: I moved on actually. But I will return to this. I don't think they have a gitter channel for Corda but I suggested that to them.

Comment: We have a slack channel (slack.corda.net) as well. CJ - can you confirm your Java version and that you are clearing the build folders?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading from JDK 10 to 8 worked for me. Here's the download link:
[Oracle Java SE Development Kit](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)